# Form based login and FormAuthenticationTicket still ask for credential

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am using ASP.NET MVC3 with Form based login.
The login process works great. But when i closed the browser and return to the page, it goes to the login page and i need to input the credential again. How can i avoid this.

This is my code for login:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
                {
                    var userprofile = svc.GetUserByUsername(model.Username);

                    var serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
                    serializeModel.Username = userprofile.Username;
                    serializeModel.Name = userprofile.Name;
                    serializeModel.DisplayAs = userprofile.DisplayAs;
                    serializeModel.MarketId = userprofile.MarketId;

                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);

                    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
                    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1,
                        model.Username,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                        true,
                        userData);

                    var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    var faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Användarnamnet eller lösenordet är felaktigt.");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a persistent cookie (set `faCookie.Expires` in your case, as you're creating the cookie manually).

See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) for more info.